# How do i push different datatypes into a void buffer?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I have the following data i need to add in the void buffer:

```
MyStruct somedata; // some struct containing ints or floats etc.
string somestring;
```

How do i do this?

This is my buffer allocation:

```
void *buffer = (void *)malloc(datasize);
```

How do i add first the `somedata` into the buffer (, which takes lets say 20 bytes), and then after 20 bytes comes the string which is variable size. I was thinking to read the structs byte by byte and add to buffer, but that feels stupid, there must be some easier way...?

**Edit:** i want this to equal to: fwrite( *struct1* ); fwrite( *struct2* ); which are called sequentially, but instead of writing to file, i want to write to a void buffer.

**Edit 2:** Made it working, heres the code:

```
char *data = (char *)malloc(datasize);

unsigned int bufferoffset = 0;

for(...){
    MyStruct somedata; // some POD struct containing ints or floats etc.
    string somestring;

    ... stuff ...

    // add to buffer:
    memcpy(data+bufferoffset, &somedata, sizeof(MyStruct));
    bufferoffset += sizeof(MyStruct);
    memcpy(data+bufferoffset, somestring.c_str(), str_len); 
    bufferoffset += str_len;
}
```

Anything to fix?

Comment: (1) You shouldn't in C++. (2) If you have to, you should know exactly what you're doing. (3) If you need to ask, then that's an indication that #2 doesn't apply. In that case, refer to #1.

Comment: Preferably, you don't. @sbi: Excellent suggestions.

Comment: i am saving data to file, so it must equal to using fwrite() sequentially. But because i made separate function for the operations, i find it cleaner if i give the data pointer to the function and it handles the saving...

Comment: @Newbie: Is this C or C++? Decide for either one. The code will be vastly different for non-PODs than for PODs, so the question whether non-PODs are on the agenda, too, is very important.

Comment: i use c++ but if theres a c-answer its fine too, which one is better is what i choose to use then.

Comment: I think you can not predict the size of the structure because of structure padding.Use sizeof() for it.

Comment: yes i am using sizeof() ! the example was just to show you that the size is a constant.

Comment: Are you only storing `string`s in the `void` buffer?  Or other datatypes as well?

Comment: i found out the correct meaning would be using char* buffer since it did indeed crash if i tried to use void* buffer... look at my edits at my question, heres the code i use now.

Comment: Newbie, why are you using `malloc()`? Indeed, this being C++ (there's a `std::string`), why do you manually allocate at all? Why not put your data into a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: @sbi: i dont know how to save vector into file in one fwrite() command, especially a vector like this... it would probably save all the string data etc... when i only need the char array without null terminating mark. Note that i am not using this data to store information, its only created before saving it, and then freed after save.

Comment: I use vector to edit/store that data, and then save it as a stream of bytes like this...

Comment: @Newbie: You can `resize()` a vector and then have the equivalent of a manually allocated array. Access its data using `&v[0]`, which gives you a pointer to the first element of an array. The main difference is that `std::vector` takes care of deallocating the array all by itself.

Comment: so i would have to loop through the data and use fwrite() multiple times... thats what im trying to avoid here, and how im supposed to pass different kinds of vectors to one function without using templates... not to mention i have no clue how such templates are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(buffer, &somedata, sizeof(MyStruct));
strcpy(buffer + sizeof(MyStruct), somestring.c_str());
```

Which will copy the string as a c string.

Comment: Note that this answer also has a `c++` tag. What happens if Newbie's `string` refers to `std::string`? (His nick is "newbie", after all.)

Comment: doesnt the memcpy() work for c_str() as well? feels weird to use different functions to different datatypes

Comment: @sbi: that's what the c_str() is for. @Newbie: you can use that too, if you want (in combination with somestring.size), but generally one uses strcpy to copy strings.

Comment: In `C`, the "problem" of using `memmove`/`memcpy` for strings is that the string needs to be scanned twice: once to calculate its length, and again to copy: `memmove(dst, src, strlen(src));`

Comment: also, if i do this in a loop, i must use `buffer += sizeof(MyStruct);` and then again `buffer += somestring.length();` ?

Comment: @pmg, well, i already calculate the length (stored in MyStruct), so theres no performance difference

Comment: @yorick: Sorry, I missed this. However, that's not oging to work for any type.

Comment: @Newbie: If it's really only PODs, this seems fine at a quick glance.

Answer (score 0):

In C, I'd do a bit like this:

```
MyStruct somedata;
string somestring;
void *buffer = (void *)malloc(datasize);

memmove(buffer, &somedata, 20);
strcpy(buffer + 20, somestring);
```

But there's **LOTS** of bad smell in the first 3 lines of this C code:

- `MyStruct` is either a typedef (why? I hate typedefs) or it should be `struct MyStruct`
- `string` is either a typedef (why? I hate typedefs) or it should be `struct string`; and identifiers starting with "str" are reserved and should not be used by programmers
- Casting the return value of `malloc` is redundant and may hide errors

---

Edit after noticing (thanks Newbie) operations on `void *`

```
char *buffer = malloc(datasize);
```

In C, `void*` and any other pointer type are assignment compatible in both directions, so there is no need to cast `char *` to `void *` when passing it to `memmove()` and friends.

```
memmove(buffer, &somedata, 20);
```

Comment: @DeadMG, according to the tags it's both C and C++ (whatever that means)

Comment: is there some other way to move the pointer than (buffer+20) instead of buffer += 20; ? i cant get buffer += 20; work at all :7

Comment: uh, seems like i have to cast it to char* instead of void* then the buffer += 20 works. any explanation for this?

Comment: Ah! Of course, sorry --- operations on `void*` are not defined. The `buffer` type should really be `unsigned char *` instead.

Comment: Depending on the destination of your buffer, you may need to copy the string terminator. If the string is "foo", str_len is 3 but you need to copy 4 bytes (the 3 letters and the '\0') ... so `memcpy(..., str_len + 1)` and `bufferoffset += str_len + 1;`

Comment: Typedefs are good because they hide internal nature of data type so make a data abstraction. I hate retyping struct to union and back everywhere when data format is changed.

Comment: @Vovanium: if you're doing "data abstraction" in "C", at a basic level such as suggested by this question/answer, either you're not doing "data abstraction" or you're not doing "C"

Comment: @pmg: the string length is saved in the MyStruct before saving the string, so when i read this file, i add the null terminator on each read string, its not saved in the file.

Comment: @pmg: Basic level data abstraction is data abstraction too. Such one may save a lot of work. And "c" is not locking you in single coding paradigm.

Comment: I hate typedefs which serve only to hide the `union` or `struct` or `enum` keyword *and do no data abstraction at all* --- is this better @Vovanium?

Comment: @pmg: Hiding wether data type is union or struct is __also data abstraction__. It makes possible to deal with data without need to know is it really struct or union. Standard fpos_t is excellent example for this: if libc does not support mb it may be long int, and with mb support it would be struct containing int and mbstate_t. And user doesn't feel the difference.

Comment: ...And typedef make program cleaner wiping much syntactic noise.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid doing this for classes which have custom copy-constructors etc.
But if you have to and you know what you're doing, use `memcpy`

Comment: Armen; I think the important distinction is PODs vs. non-PODs.

Comment: @fahad: memcpy can generally be optimized a bit better, because it's a requirement that the source and destinations do not overlap (as is the case here), while memmove can be used to copy to overlapping source/destinations. So if you're sure the source and destination will not overlap, memcpy is generally better.

Comment: This time I chose the informal way. Because otherwise I had to explain what a POD is. But, as you recall, whichever way I choose, you just HAVE to tell me I should have chosen the  opposite :))

Comment: @Armen: Yep, you have found out the way it works now. `:)` (Really, would you care to write a `c++-faq` POD Q/A? It would be nice to be able to link to it.)

Comment: @sbi: you mean to ask a question and answer it myself?

Comment: @Armen: Yep. That's certainly a worthwhile topic for an FAQ. Would be handy to link to all the time.

Comment: @sbi: OK, I'll do it one of these days :)

Comment: @Armen: Leave a link here @addressed to me, so that I see it. I'd hate to miss this.

Comment: @sbi: POD FAQ as promised :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-how-are-they-special